Set temporary variable in bash script does not work
I try to simply check if a branch contains a tag in order to continue the pipeline only if the tag is on master. I use a composite action that it is called in a reusable GitHub Actions workflow.
This is the code: enter code here
name: 'Check branch eligibility for production deployment'
description: 'Run bash script that check the branch eligibility for production deployment. We use composite to avoid duplicate it into GitHub workflows'

runs:
  using: "composite"
  steps:
    - name: Run the bash script to check branch eligibility of production deployment
      shell: bash --noprofile --norc -eo pipefail -o xtrace {0}
      run: |
        GITHUB_REF_TYPE='tag'
        if [[ $GITHUB_REF_TYPE == 'tag' ]]; then
            echo "It is a tag, so we check if the tag is on master."
            tag_name=${GITHUB_REF#refs/}
            echo "TAG NAME: $tag_name"
            git branch -r --contains "$tag_name"
            echo "RC command: $?"
            branch="$(git branch -r --contains "$tag_name")"
            echo "RC: $?"
            branch_2='test'
            env
            echo "git branch -r --contains $tag_name"
            echo "branch: $branch"

              if [[ $branch == "origin/master" ]] ; then
                echo "Tag $GITHUB_REF_NAME is on master, so the pipeline can continue."
              else
                echo "Tag is not on protected branch. Abort build."
                exit 1
              fi
        else
          echo "$GITHUB_REF_NAME is not a tag. Abort build."
          exit 1
        fi

I put some echos to debug and I remark that variable branches is always empty instead of branches_2 that I set with "test".
I use -o xtrace option, and this is the following output of the script (without all the env command output, that it is too long):
+ [[ tag == \t\a\g ]]
+ echo 'It is a tag, so we check if the tag is on master.'
It is a tag, so we check if the tag is on master.
+ tag_name=tags/2.0.0
+ echo 'TAG NAME: tags/2.0.0'
+ git branch -r --contains tags/2.0.0
TAG NAME: tags/2.0.0
+ echo 'RC command: 0'
RC command: 0
++ git branch -r --contains tags/2.0.0
+ branch=
RC: 0
+ echo 'RC: 0'
+ branches_2=test
+ env
SELENIUM_JAR_PATH=/usr/share/java/selenium-server.jar
+ echo 'git branch -r --contains tags/2.0.0'
CONDA=/usr/share/miniconda
+ echo 'branch: '
branch_2=test
_=/usr/bin/env
git branch -r --contains tags/2.0.0
BRANCH: 

I use environment variables in order to check if that is the difference with basic bash variables but the result is the same.
The fact is that as branch is empty the for loop does not run anything.
What is happening?

Simplify any potential debugging by creating a working bash script first THEN put it into whatever environment you want to call it from. Copy/paste your bash script into http://shellcheck.net and fix the issues it'll tell you about as a starting point.

I'd start by putting set -o xtrace at the start of the Bash code to get a detailed trace of what the code is doing.  See How can I debug a Bash script? and the Debugging section of BashGuide/Practices - Greg's Wiki.

Make sure to include the debugging output in your question. It'll be useful for us to also see the output of echo "TAG NAME: $tag_name", git branch -r --contains $tag_name, etc.

Just to note, there is no reason to export the variables. They aren't used outside the immediate script by other commands.

As this is a GitHub action, do you expect there to be any remote branches? Does git branch -r actually show any output the first time you run it, and if not, does dropping the -r resolve the issue?

@EdMorton yeah, I already did that. I begin by creating a bash script and all works as expected. The point is I can't explain why the BRANCHES variable remains empty in GitHub actions

@EdMorton I edited my question with the output of my bash with the -o xtrace option

Your xtrace says you're assigning to branches= even though your "real" code is assigning to BRANCHES=. These aren't identical names (and you should be using all-lowercase names for your own variables per POSIX convention)

That said, the "real" problem is more likely related to either the state of the environment, or active environment variables (git can have environment variables set telling it to work on a repo other than the current-directory one, and it's not uncommon for CI tools to set some of those variables).

(I'm also curious how you tested output from git branch -r -- if you only ran it locally and assume that the output is the same in CI, that's not a safe assumption)

@chepner Yeah, I know, I began by using basic variables but I don't understand why the affectation does not work so I test with export to check if the issue persists. I did that to see the output of env command

Your trace output isn't consistent with the code you've shown. It's attempting to set branches (though it's still empty), not BRANCHES.

Where does GITHUB_REF get set? I suspect a trailing carriage return, so that the value of TAGS is not what the output of echo suggests.

(Either that, or you simply don't have a tag named tags/2.0.0.)

@CharlesDuffy yes, I use to set my variables with lowercases but I try to use export (with the naming in uppercase) to show output with env command after that. I try to understand why does the var is still empty.
In my CICD, I have a checkout of my repository (there is not present into my question) so I run, as you cas see, the command and the output is tags/2.0.0.

@chepner GITHUB_REF is an environment variable that GitHub initializes with the reference of a commit or tag that trigger it (https://docs.github.com/en/actions/writing-workflows/choosing-what-your-workflow-does/store-information-in-variables). I try to follow your tip about carriage return but for your other assumption I can confirm that the tag exists :)

@chepner you are right, I change the names of variables (switch them from uppercases to lowercases) and I am not using the export anymore. I edited my question

You're populating branches (branches="$(git branch -r --contains $tag_name)") but then trying to loop on the contents of BRANCHES (for branch in $BRANCHES; do) which is not the same variable, it's a different variable that you never populate as http://shellcheck.net would tell you (see my first comment), and your debugging statements like echo "BRANCHES: $branches" are making your debugging output confusing by display the wrong variable name for the value.

I’m voting to close this question because the poster didn't use http://shellcheck.net as directed by the [tag:bash] tag.

@EdMorton But the trace output shows that branches is empty anyway, so while the case is an issue, it doesn't explain why git branch -r ... isn't returning any output.

A [mcve] would be tag_name=${GITHUB_REF#refs/}; git branch -r --contains $tag_name. Again, I suspect that tag_name isn't really tags/2.0.0, but something like tags/2.0.0\r

@chepner, ...if the shell is really  bash, xtrace output would be showing us that carriage return already. (If it's /bin/sh, granted, bets are off).

@J-Are, a good place to start might be to add a command declare -p "${GIT@}" >&2 -- that'll print contents of variables most likely to be causing surprises here by modifying git's behavior.

@EdMorton I already use shellcheck.net but no issues appear. I can run my script without issue into my local env but the problem persists in GitHub runner. I did not have more information so if you think you can"t help me with all what I provide, you can close. I will continue to look for on my side and I will put a comment with the solution when I will foind it.

(BTW, for branch in $branches is an antipattern -- if you want to treat a variable as a list, it should be an array -- but it's also not a direct cause of the problem at hand)

@J-Are every iteration of the script in your question, including the current one, have had issues that shellcheck would tell you about.

@EdMorton it is normal that issue appear if you take it as it is because GITHUB_REF_TYPE is set by Github itself at the pipeline initialization. I copy/paste my script and only initialize the variable as I edit in my question. (with "tag"). I swear it was not issue triggered by shellcheck.
Don't worry, you can close, the error is because my code checkout with github action have need to set an input to fetch all repository information

I understand that you believe the problem was caused by an issue other than one of the ones that shellcheck would identify but several people have wasted their time thinking about and telling you about issues that shellcheck would have told you about so even if you think none of those issues matter, it's always good to clean them up before asking anyone else to read your code.

don't you need to action/checkout the repo first?

@EdMorton I understand sorry for that, it was the third time I ask question on stackoverflow and I always deep dive the subject before asking question on it. I will answer to my own question with what I did to fix my issue.

@KamilCuk I did that into another and I find why my command does not return anything. It is because I need to pass an argument to my checkout. I will answer to my own question with the solution
